Terraform init returning non-zero exit status code 127
Error msg:
ERROR:root:Error initializing Terraform and Terraformer
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/app/import_tf.py", line 83, in initialise_terraform_to_import_state_file
    initialize_terraform()
  File "/app/util/state_file.py", line 108, in initialize_terraform
    subprocess.run(['terraform', 'init'], shell=True, check=True, stdout=subprocess.DEVNULL, stderr=subprocess.DEVNULL)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/subprocess.py", line 512, in run
    output=stdout, stderr=stderr)
subprocess.CalledProcessError: Command '['terraform', 'init']' returned non-zero exit status 127.
ERROR:root:{'error': CalledProcessError(127, ['terraform', 'init'])}
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/app/import_tf.py", line 42, in get_tf_state_files
    aws_secret_access_key, region, all_services)
  File "/app/import_tf.py", line 98, in initialise_terraform_to_import_state_file
    raise e
  File "/app/import_tf.py", line 83, in initialise_terraform_to_import_state_file
    initialize_terraform()
  File "/app/util/state_file.py", line 108, in initialize_terraform
    subprocess.run(['terraform', 'init'], shell=True, check=True, stdout=subprocess.DEVNULL, stderr=subprocess.DEVNULL)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/subprocess.py", line 512, in run
    output=stdout, stderr=stderr)
subprocess.CalledProcessError: Command '['terraform', 'init']' returned non-zero exit status 127.

This is my docker file
FROM python:3.7
# Install necessary packages
RUN apt-get update && \
    apt-get install -y curl unzip && \
    rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/*
# Download and install Terraform 1.8.1
RUN curl -LO https://releases.hashicorp.com/terraform/1.8.1/terraform_1.8.1_linux_amd64.zip && \
    unzip terraform_1.8.1_linux_amd64.zip -d /usr/local/bin && \
    rm terraform_1.8.1_linux_amd64.zip
# Download and install Terraformer
RUN curl -LO https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/terraformer/releases/download/$(curl -s https://api.github.com/repos/GoogleCloudPlatform/terraformer/releases/latest | grep tag_name | cut -d '"' -f 4)/terraformer-linux-amd64 && \
    chmod +x terraformer-linux-amd64 && \
    mv terraformer-linux-amd64 /usr/local/bin/terraformer
# Set working directory
WORKDIR /app
# Add /usr/local/bin to PATH
ENV PATH="/usr/local/bin:${PATH}"
ADD https://github.com/ufoscout/docker-compose-wait/releases/download/2.2.1/wait /wait
RUN chmod +x /wait
ENV LOGLEVEL INFO
EXPOSE 5000
COPY requirements.txt ./
RUN pip install --no-cache-dir -r requirements.txt
COPY src /app
CMD /wait && python ./app.py


This is the code where I am trying to run the terraform command using python
def initialize_terraform():
    logging.info("Initializing terraform")
    subprocess.run(['terraform', 'init'], shell=True, check=True, stdout=subprocess.DEVNULL, stderr=subprocess.DEVNULL)
    logging.info("completed the terraform initialization")


When I run the docker file, my expectation is, it should run the terraform command and return the exit status code 0
I cross verified by checking terraform --version inside the container and it is working and installed properly. The terraform is installed in this particular path inside container /usr/local/bin/terraform
Inside the docker container the terraform is installed properly, that's why when I run terraform init explicitly inside the shell it is working. But when I try running terraform init from my python code, it returns the 127 error, So I am assuming it is not able to find the executable path of terraform within the container. The path where terraform is installed in the container is /usr/local/bin/terraform. I have tried some ways like setting the path where I see the terraform installed as env-> like this ENV PATH="/usr/local/bin:${PATH}" but it is not helping
Looking forward to some help

Could you please edit your question and include the error message?

just now edited

looks like more context in the error is needed, it could be that python is hiding part of the error, can you troubleshoot this further by running terraform init just from the shell ... also look into: https://developer.hashicorp.com/terraform/internals/debugging

Here is what we know ... you tested terraform --version and it is working ... then you mention: return of code 127 means that the executable terraform is not accessible that contradicts the first statement.

Please just try subprocess.run(['terraform', 'init']) see what it gives

I have run "terraform init" explicitly inside container and it works as expected, but when I run through this way from inside my code = subprocess.run(['terraform', 'init'], shell=True, check=True, stdout=subprocess.DEVNULL, stderr=subprocess.DEVNULL)
It is returning me 127
So it basically means terraform was properly installed in the container, but
subprocess.run(['terraform', 'init'], shell=True, check=True, stdout=subprocess.DEVNULL, stderr=subprocess.DEVNULL)
Is not being able to access terraform executable file. Thus the 127 error
@HelderSepulveda
Pls correct me if I am wrong

Did you try subprocess.run(['terraform', 'init']) ?  what did you get? maybe one of those additional params is not supposed to be there
